# Sending simple email on Azure with Sendgrid

Tags: c#, azure, email, azure-functions, sendgrid

I am trying to send email using `SendGrid` on `Azure`.
I followed these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email ; but it doesn't seem to work.
. Sending via `smtp` works though.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

namespace Example
{
    internal class Example
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Execute().Wait();
        }

        static async Task Execute()
        {
            var apiKey = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("from@hotmail.com", "DX Team"),
                Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp SDK!",
                PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
                HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("to@gmail.com", "Test User"));
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looking at that class - assuming it ran.. it would run the email once.

Comment: Can you check the error in the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code sample, it would run well while you do not receive any email.

So pay attention to some points as below:

1.When you create api key, make sure that you choose the **Full Access**.
[image]
2.You use Gmail to receive email, so set "**Allow less secure apps:ON**".
[image]
3.Check the response, if the `StatusCode` is **Accepted** it means it send email successfully.
[image]
Then test agian, and it may work well.

Also, you want to make an function which is send email every 15 minutes.

You could refer to the code as below, I create azure function in v1.

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */15 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, [SendGrid(ApiKey = "sendgridkey")] out SendGridMessage message, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            message = new SendGridMessage();
            message.AddTo("testto@gmail.com");
            message.AddContent("text/html", "Test body");
            message.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("testfrom@gmail.com"));
            message.SetSubject("Subject");

        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much this detailed answer but I make something wrong I guess. I cant stop program with break point so I cant see any statuscode -_- I'm diging web to fix this or can you share project package with me to understand whats wrong with my code ? Thank you again. Have a nice day

Comment: You need to set your `Sloution Configuration` as `Debug`. And here is how to [debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx).

Comment: Everything gives null :( Also I cant reach my sengridkey too. I dont understand why:/
https://imgur.com/gHpIn7z

Comment: According to the image, you put the sendgridkey in app.config or in appsetting on portal, the way you retrieve key value is correct. And you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email) for more detail about sendgrid. Calm down, and do the troubleshooting.

Comment: This article doesnt explain this "App Service" thing on Azure portal. I clicked on App Service and opened some function then added api key. But there are a lot of app service here. Which one do I need to choose ?

https://imgur.com/ZdcLEs1

Comment: Click your function and click the "Application Settings" and add your sendkey like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMGS2.png).

Comment: I added this key when I opened this topic :( Checked it and it is here :/

https://imgur.com/mNwk78y

But interesting thing is your key less character than mine. hmm

Comment: That's ok. I just do a sample how to add appsettings.

Comment: I gave my key in string. This time works. First I need to fix why visual studio cant connect to azure and take my api key. Then learn how to add your azure function :D 

https://imgur.com/EPKOfJH

Comment: When you work in local, you could set your key in local.setting.json file.

Comment: No, I don't want to work locally. Just tried. Can you tell me which file or code is missing here to connect azure and take the key. 

https://imgur.com/cQghRQF

PS: Sorry I take your time. Thank you for help.

Comment: Have you published the function to azure?

Comment: And the image you provided is a console app,not a function.

Comment: Hi Joey. It's me again :( Can you help me to make this scheduled mail on v3. I'm freaking out and didnt find any help to me :( Helpful people send documents to me but I dont understand how to implant this time trigger in mail function. I tried a lot of things but nothing happened. Also tried your V1 function but VS gives error at "SendGridMessage" etc.

Comment: In vs, I could not install v3 function. If you have some new knowledge, glad to share with me to learn.

Comment: With your code I took this error. VS doesnt show any error.
https://imgur.com/cOaSA9Z

Comment: You could try to add your local.setting.json and portal.So that you could test both in local and azure.

Comment: Hmm. I also realise that there are 2 version here not 3. Finally find where can I choose V1 function. Anyway. I need to learn which code I need to write in local.settings.json. Lets dig it. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Joey! Thank you so much man. Finally I understand what the hell is this Locally thing. I just added "AzureWebJobsSendGridApiKey": "SG.blablabla" and it works. I also learn we can connect storage account in here (local.settings.json). I really bother you but thank you again to continue answer my messages.

Comment: Glad to see you solved the problem. You are welcome.