# Issues using SendGrid with Azure ML

Tags: python, sendgrid, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to send an email using SendGrid within Azure Machine Learning. This is initially just a basic test email to ensure it is working correctly.

The steps I have taken:

1. Pip installed SendGrid;
2. Zipped the SendGrid download and uploaded as a dataset to AML platform;
3. Attempted to run the example SendGrid Python code (which can be seen below):

I have copied steps in similar posts concerning uploading modules to AML [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222606/updating-pandas-to-version-0-19-in-azure-ml-studio/46232963#46232963) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523924/adding-python-modules-to-azureml-workspace) as well as ensuring the correct settings for the SendGrid API key were established on setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078310/sending-simple-email-on-azure-with-sendgrid).

```py
def azureml_main():

    import sendgrid
    from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
    from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail


    message = Mail(
        from_email='xxx@xyz.com',
        to_emails='xxx@xyz.com',
        subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
        html_content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>')
    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SG API Code'))
        response = sg.send(message)
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.body)
        print(response.headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

No error message is returned in the terminal. To me this indicates there weren't any issues with the code, yet no emails have been received/sent.

```
python ScheduleRun.py 
azureuser@will1:~/cloudfiles/code/Users/will/Schedule$ 
azureuser@will1:~/cloudfiles/code/Users/will/Schedule$ python ScheduleRun.py 
azureuser@will1:~/cloudfiles/code/Users/will/Schedule$
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

When you run the code nothing is printed, which is concerning as neither the success or error `print`s are called.

If the code you have shared is the entirety of the file then I think the code is simply not running. You have defined a function but you have not called the function itself.

Try calling `azureml_main()` on the last line of the file:

```py
        print(response.headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

azureml_main()
```

One other thing that concerns me is this line:

```py
os.environ.get('SG API Code')
```

It looks as though you intend to actually place your SG API Key in the call to `os.environ.get`. Instead, that string should be the identifier for an environment variable that you have set. For example, you should set the SendGrid API key as an environment variable called `SENDGRID_API_KEY` and then in your code fetch the API key by calling `os.environ.get("SENDGRID_API_KEY")`. Check out this post on [working with environment variables in Python](https://www.twilio.com/blog/environment-variables-python) for more.